# How to copy a dictionary of lists?

Tags: python, dictionary, deep-copy

How can i copy a dictionary of lists and what is its complexity? The dictionary I'm tryint to copy is something like this:

```
myDict = { 'k1': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 
           'k2': ['d', 'e', 'f'], 
           'k3': ['g', 'h', 'i'] }
```

Comment: `from copy import deepcopy`

Comment: So… Why do you need to do this? If you're worried about its complexity, that implies you've got a performance problem, and maybe the answer is to figure out a design that doesn't require the copy?

Comment: @abarnert yes, i just wanted to change <a  href='http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106736/is-this-algorithm-good-for-finding-the-longest-common-subsequence'> my old algorithm </a> and map all indexs to letters instead of using ystr.find(cl, start) use dictionary to find letters in O(1). but now i found that its not efficient.

Comment: Why does that require deep-copying the map? (Also, we all assumed you need a deep copy here, but… do you? If you just want a shallow copy of the map, you can obviously do that a lot faster. (Basically, it ought to just copy the hash-table and incref all of the keys and values.)

Comment: @abarnert Where can i post my Modified code?

Comment: http://pastebin.com always works if you just want to post it for people to review. http://gist.github.com is better if you want to be able edit it with full version history.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest way to copy any complex data structure is [`copy.deepcopy`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy). (If you were thinking about doing it yourself, see [the source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Lib/copy.py#l129) to get an idea of what's involved.)

The complexity should obviously be O(NM), where N is the number of `dict` entries and M the average number of `list` entries. But let's work through it:

Let's say you have a `dict` of N key/value pairs, each value being a `list` with an average of M elements.

If the `list`s were simple values, you'd need to allocate 1 hash table, and do 2N+1 simple copies and possibly N hashes. The `string`s are immutable, and they're all length 1 anyway, and if they weren't, Python caches hash values in large strings. So, we've got O(N) total operations.

But the `list`s are not simple values. You need to allocate a new list and copy `M` elements. That takes O(M) time. Since there are N of them, that's O(NM).

So, the total time is O(N + NM) = O(NM).

And, given that you have NM objects and explicitly want to copy all of them, there's really no way you could beat that.

Of course it's conceivable that you could get an order of magnitude improvement by stripping down the extraneous parts of what `deepcopy` does and porting any tight loops left over into Cython or C.

Comment: Since this answer was accepted, and only answered the second half of the question, I edited it to include the first place (which Volatility already gave before me).

Comment: befor Volatility, l4mpi's comment helped me, so i accepted your answer.

Answer (score 11):

```
from copy import deepcopy
myCopy = deepcopy(myDict)
```

`deepcopy` is always **the** way.

Comment: *mostly* always the way ;)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the internal dictionary method called `copy()` to copy a dictionary:

example:

```
a = {'s':[1,2,3], 'f':[5,4,2]}
b = a.copy()
```

if you change `a` the `b` doesn't change.

and the complexity is near `O(1)`, because dictionaries use hash tables to store data ,  accessing its data is near `O(1)`, then for the lists, accessing data and memory proccesses are constant time.so it is near `O(1)`.

Comment: mydict is a dictionary of list, so if i use copy, when i change list it'll change my original list.

Comment: in terms of lists you should use list[:] to copy them first, then work on the copy to not change the original but in terms of dictionaries, I've tried it on python 2.7.3 and it worked.

Comment: I would assume the complexity is still O(N)

Comment: I've also tired it on python 2.7.3 but it doesn't work. can you test this code?seq = [1,5,9], d = {'a':seq, 'b':[2,6,8]}, td = d.copy(), td['a'].append(52), print d, what is the output?

Comment: in the test you are about,Yes, instead of .copy() you should first import copy then use td = copy.deepcopy(d).and the complexity of deepcopy is O(N) because it recursively copies objects.

Comment: Yes i already saw that after answers but "نوش دارو پس از مرگ سهراب" doesn't make sense.